# How to get elements with the different value of the same attribute in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, attributes, attr

I need to find elements with the different value of the same attribute...
This works-> **`$data.find("div[data-alpha='1']");`**
But i need something like this-> **`$data.find('div[data-alpha='1']' + 'div[data-alpha='2']`'** ....
So i want to find all elements which have the ,,data-alpha" atribute 1 or 2.
Anyone have an idea how to do that? 
Thanks for all answers! Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`multiple-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```
$data.find("div[data-alpha='1'], div[data-alpha='2']")
```

This allows you to accumulate the results of different selectors by joining the selectors with a comma into a single selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try the add() method (http://api.jquery.com/add/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all elements with the data-alpha attribute use

```
$data.find([data-alpha])
```

If you need elements with specific values, use:

```
$data.find([data-alpha=x],[data-alpha=y])
```